# How to make a da capo or dal segno playback include repeats in MuseScore?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, musescore, repeats

I'm currently writing in MuseScore, and I have a problem getting the desired playback using dal segno: the second time through, repeat signs are ignored.

[According to this link](http://www.ars-nova.com/Theory%20Q&A/Q109.html), inner repeats in a dal segno section don't get taken the second time through. If this is true, is there some sort of standard way to make a dal segno include repeats?

Also, can I just copy-paste the segno section or is this a less accepted way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pragmatic answer: if there is a way to notate that repeats are to be played on D.C. or D.S., it is not well known. I'm not saying there is no such standard, only that it is not widespread.

The best you can do is to write it out: "*D.S. with repeats*", or "*D.S con repetizione*" if you prefer italian.

Comment: In the musescore forums that is indeed the given suggestion regarding notation, although that won't solve the playback problem. 
Apparently this (not being able to specify repeats in jumps for playback) is a known behaviour (either bug or feature is not clear). If proper playback is an absolute requirement, I have not seen and can't think of a better suggestion than making a copy of your score just for playback and dupplicate the required sections.

Comment: @joseem Musescore is mainly a notation program. Playback is a useful feature, but is merely there as a help to notate. If playback features are what matters to you, you could change the music as you suggest, but it won't look as good for live musicians. If you don't plan to print the music and give it to musicians, you might be using the wrong tool for the job. Look into sequencers (Rosegarden?) in that case.

Answer (score 3):

To get playback of repeats within a dal segno section...

In a score like this,

[image: repeats inside D.S. section]

select the jump indicator (here, the "D.S."), and in the Element Inspector, check the "Play repeats" option. (the `F8` key toggles the Inspector on Windows.)

[image: D.S. selected and Play repeats checked]

---

Verified in MuseScore 3.5.2.